# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: item):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I have programmed an android app, which can take profile pictures from a user. Now I want to upload these profile picture to my Ruby on Rail server. However the upload doesn't work. I receive the Error message:

```
  app/controllers/items_controller.rb:55:in `item_params'
    app/controllers/items_controller.rb:21:in `create'
    Started POST "/items" for 192.168.3.7 at 2016-09-11 01:12:21 +0900
    Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x5737110 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Clemens/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160911-2
    8624-1vjbftr.jpg>, @original_filename="IMG_20160911_010525.jpg", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; na
    me=\"image\"; filename=\"IMG_20160911_010525.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n">}
    Completed 400 Bad Request in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: item):

app/controllers/items_controller.rb:55:in `item_params'
app/controllers/items_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Why does this not work? How should my item_params be defined? Here is my **items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /items
  # GET /items.json
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  # GET /items/1
  # GET /items/1.json
  def show
    send_data(item.file_contents,
              type: @item.content_type,
              filename: @item.filename)
  end

  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    if @item.save
      render :show, status: :created, location: @item
    else
      render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /items/1.json
  def update
    if @item.update(item_params)
      render :show, status: :ok, location: @item
    else
      render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  # DELETE /items/1.json
  def destroy
    @item.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def item_params
      #######################params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :picture)
      params.permit(:picture)
    end
end
```

UPDATE: I renamed my image from android app and called it "item". Now the parameter error disappears. However a new error arises:

```
app/controllers/items_controller.rb:24:in `create'
Started POST "/items" for 192.168.3.7 at 2016-09-11 10:25:26 +0900
Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"item"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x53b1d30 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Clemens/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160911-3144-anlpp6.jpg>, @original_filename="IMG_20160911_100920.jpg", @co
ntent_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"item\"; filename=\"IMG_20160911_100920.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n"
>}
Unpermitted parameter: item
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (31.2ms)  INSERT INTO `items` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-09-11 01:25:26', '2016-09-11 01:25:26')
   (0.0ms)  COMMIT
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 62ms (ActiveRecord: 31.2ms)



ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template items/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/rails-api-fileupload-tutorial-carrierwave-single/app/views"
):

app/controllers/items_controller.rb:24:in `create'
```

Any idea why I get this error? I put in views following line both in views\application\show.json.jbuilder and in views\items\show.json.jbuilder:

```
json.extract! @item, :locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]
```

However I still get the same error.

Comment: `params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :picture)` why is this commented out?

Comment: I am pretty sure it wasn't at the time he saw that error message! :)

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that this line:

```
params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :picture)
```

will raise an exception if you do not have an item in your params.  When you are sending to your create action, apparently you do not have an item.  I am also assuming that when you saw this error you didn't have that line commented.

Comment: Your assuming is right. After I was surprised by this error I commented this line out, because I just send an image and not a name or description. So I need to rename my Image I send from my android app, call it "item" and the problem is solved?

Comment: I renamed my image to "items", see UPDATE in my post. Something is still wrong with my parameters. I don't know how ruby on rails can use the parameters sent from android. I don't know what to do

Comment: Item is not the same as item.  You can send a parameter called item that has 3 fields being :name, :description, and :picture.  Any additional fields on item, or any param not called item is straight out.

Comment: It worked with item. I can now upload the image. I get the "Completed 201" message. Now comes the next step: how can I have access in Ruby on Rails on this item? I really dont know

Comment: You access it by calling @item.  Please mark my answer as correct if I helped you!